# Generate a bitcoin core private key from a seed phrase

Tags: javascript, python, bitcoin

Bitcoin core don't use seed phrase so I am trying to convert the seed phrase to private key, for some reason the output is not correct.

Here's my code:

```
import bip39 from "bip39";
import * as bitcoin from "bitcoinjs-lib";
var mnemonic = "all all all all all all all all all all all all";
var seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
var privateKey = bitcoin.bip32.fromSeed(seed).derivePath("m/0'/0'").privateKey;

var wallet = bitcoin.bip32.fromSeed(seed);

var publicKey = bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({
 pubkey: wallet.derivePath("m/0'/0'").publicKey,
}).address;

console.log(privateKey.toString("hex"));
console.log(publicKey);
```

I know that bitcoin core has derivation path of `m/0'/0'` but I also tried other path with no success.

Any idea where I went wrong?

I looked for other solutions but couldn't find one that worked

Answer (score 4):

Sir, this should help you to to convert a seed phrase to a private key

```
// Import necessary libraries
const bip39 = require("bip39");
const bitcoin = require("bitcoinjs-lib");
const HDKey = require("hdkey");
const CoinKey = require("coinkey");

// Replace 'your 12-word mnemonic here' with your actual 12-word mnemonic.
const mnemonic =
  "replace swamp motion employ inch amused ritual clown liberty remove orbit budget";

// Convert the mnemonic to a seed
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);

// Create an HD wallet key from the seed
const hdKey = HDKey.fromMasterSeed(Buffer.from(seed, "hex"));

// Define the BIP44 path for Bitcoin (m/44'/0'/0'/0/0)
const path = "m/44'/0'/0'/0/0";

// Derive a child key from the HD key using the defined path
const child = hdKey.derive(path);

// Create a CoinKey from the derived child private key and specify the Bitcoin network
const coinKey = new CoinKey(child.privateKey, bitcoin.networks.bitcoin);

// Prepare an object with address, path, private key, and Wallet Import Format (WIF) key
const info = {
  address: coinKey.publicAddress,          // Bitcoin public address
  path,                                    // BIP44 path
  privateKey: coinKey.privateKey.toString("hex"), // Private key in hexadecimal
  WIF: coinKey.privateWif,                 // Wallet Import Format (WIF) private key
};

// Log the information to the console
console.info(info);
```

This will produce the output

```
{
  address: '1KDAsrVmvSeDAs8P2nqSFRhABhNfu1aM9T',
  path: "m/44'/0'/0'/0/0",
  privateKey: '254fbbc7e390f88539d832daa4d03db502648666581417dcdecfae3a2ae23175',
  WIF: 'KxUEqsUXePmjrVP5SHvWykpJU4oM7S4bnTvsQSZnU5TAvD9wWzon'
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample for generating a BIP84 address? I guess changing the path is not enough. I have also tried generating a 24 word mnemonic